# Honestly have no Idea how to prove A v ¬¬B from A v B (LPL Q. 6.18)

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic

```
Premise  A v B
Goal     A v ¬¬B
```

Please help. It seems so self evident but I don't know how to get there.

Comment: Try disjunction elimination. Each of the disjuncts leads to the conclusion.

Comment: You say that the textbook is `LPL`. Did you mean "Language, Proof, and Logic" by Jon Barwise and John Etchemendy?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof that uses a different proof checker than the one you are using so it will require understanding the proof to make use of it.

[image]

Note that the premise is a disjunction, an or-statement. To use the premise, I have to consider two cases, *A* and *B*. For each case I assume the case and then I need to derive the goal: *A ∨ ¬¬B*. If I can do that for each case, then I can use disjunction elimination (vE), as I did on the last line, to discharge the two assumptions (lines 2 and 4) and derive the goal.

That is the basic plan of the proof.

However, each case has its own details to consider.

- For the *A* case, I can use disjunction introduction (vI) to join with *A* anything I want. What I need is *¬¬B* and so that is what I use on line 3.
- For the *B* case, I need to first convert *B* to *¬¬B*. I do that by assuming *¬B* (line 5) with hopes of deriving a contradiction which I am able to do on line 6. On line 7 I can use negation introduction (¬I) to add the desired negation which also discharges the assumption on line 5. What I have left to do is use disjunction introduction to get the desired result for this case on line 8.

You will likely have to enter lines differently to make your proof checker work. Links to the proof checker that I used and the textbook associated with it are listed below.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Fall 2019. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf

Answer (score -1):

LEMMA 1. `A --> (A v ¬¬B)`

```
line1 ......       A   ........... assumption
line2 ...... A v ¬¬B   ........... 1, Disjunction introduction
```

LEMMA 1. `B --> (A v ¬¬B)`

```
line1 ......      B   ........... assumption
line2 ......    ¬¬B   ........... 1, Double negation
line3 ...... A v ¬¬B  ........... 2, Disjunction introduction
```

**THEOREM**   `(A v B) --> (A v ¬¬B)`

```
line1 ......   A v B   ........... assumption
line2 ...... A v ¬¬B   ........... line 1, proof by cases on lemma 1 and lemma 2
QED
```